# How to smooth a wide stepped bitmap?

Tags: bitmap, 2d, antialiasing, smoothing, heightmap

I have 2D data with steps of different heights with different spacings. I want to reverse the quantisation and recreate an approximation of the original surface.

[Example of heavily stepped data, and desired smooth result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMpjF.jpg)

I don't mind if there are artifacts and the shape varies, but I do want C1 continuity over the surface where possible, and a new quantisation should produce the same stepped data (can be a bit lossy but that is the ideal)

I’ve tried cubic interpolation & gaussian blurs. They either have too local an impact, or destroy details in the original.

Ideally a row of steps should produce a straight line whether it is a 1 pixel wide step or 100. And subsequent steps of varying sizes should produce a smooth, continuous line.

Practically I want to use this as a 8bit to float convertor to remove banding on single intensity steps like 127...128 If the values vary by more than a small tolerance (1?) then they should be kept as sharp edges.

One idea is to separate out islands of the same value, clamp their boundary heights and relax the interior. This would remove the steps, but the boundaries would still be creases with discontinuous gradients.

Extending the fixed boundary idea - I could relax in value and also in gradient - while keeping a set of boundary points fixed in value over the image.

I wonder if there is a better angle to approach this problem from, or any good prior work.

*** UPDATE
I tried **Bilateral Smoothing**, but found it left artefacts in areas where the smoothing radius differs greatly from the step length. Although Bilateral may be useful as a post-process on a range-independent smoothing calculation.

I tried an inversed mipmap approach - didn't work.

Current best attempt is a multidirectional quadratic height estimation - with weighted quality voting for the best direction to use at each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Current best attempt is a multidirectional quadratic height estimation - with weighted quality voting for the best direction to use at each pixel.

Slow as anything but good enough result. Main artefact is a sharpening at very steep edges. Could operate on an upscaled version and then downscale again to antialias.

[image: Current step smooth]